# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find view '~/templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml'. The following locations were searched:

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rotativa

luego de actualizar la version de .Net core desde la version 3.1 a la version 6 de mi proyecto estoy teniendo una excepcion al momento de buscar un view, independienteme de que use `View()` o que use `ViewAsPdf()`, los mismos anteriormente funcionaba en la version de 3.1 de .net core .

la excepcion es :`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find view '~/templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml'. The following locations were searched: ~/templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml`

el codigo en el controlador es este:

```
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("htmlpdf")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadPDFAsync(int cropId, int fieldId, int growerId)
    {
        var info = await new ReportService(_context, _mapper, _config).CropActivityReportAsync(cropId, fieldId, growerId);
       // string HTMLContent = await RazorTemplateEngine.RenderAsync("templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml", info);
         return new ViewAsPdf("~/templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml", info) { FileName="Report.pdf"};
    }
```

el Startup.cs:

```
namespace FieldTrace.WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

          
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Adding CORS to services - doesn't mean we use it. Just have it included incase we are in development environment we can app.use it inside Configure method.
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithExposedHeaders("iHeight", "iWidth") );
            });
            services.AddOptions<EmailSendConfigure>().Bind(Configuration.GetSection("emailConfig"));
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            );

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapping());
            });

            IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper);
            services.AddControllersWithViews();



            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });
            services.AddDbContextPool<Context>(options => options
              // replace with your connection string
              .UseMySQL(Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionString:DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = " WebAPI", Version = "v1" });
            });
            

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //If we are in development mode, then enable the CORS so we can test
                app.UseCors("AllowMyOrigin");
            }

            app.UseSwagger();


            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", " WebAPI V1");

            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();


            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
     
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            Rotativa.AspNetCore.RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
        }
    }
}
```

el cshtml esta en la ruta que especifico en el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

algo extraño es que desde visual studio y IIS no funciona pero corriendo el comando `dotnet run` si funciona.

alguien sabe como podria solucionar este error, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: mi problema es que estoy obteniendo este error : `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find view '~/templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml'. The following locations were searched: ~/templates/CropActivityReport.cshtml`  luego de haber actualizado la version de Net desde la 3.1 a la version 6

Answer (score 0):

Puede que algunos componentes no sean compactibles con la versión de *.net core 6*

1. Puedes dar *clic en solución* del proyecto,seleccionando limpiar y recompilar proyecto
2. Verifica que los paquetes esten en la nueva versión

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).